My data has repeated column names. How to keep only the first row as names and set IDs as a new column?
First is my original data frame.

df1 <- structure(list(REF = c("REF", "T", "C", "T", "REF", "T", "C", 
"REF", "G", "T"), ALT = c("ALT", "G", "G", "C", "ALT", "G", "G", 
"ALT", "A", "C"), INFO = c("INFO", "AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=2.56;DB;DP=394;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=14.20;ReadPosRankSum=1.08;SOR=0.674", 
"AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=3.000e-03;DB;DP=263;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.451;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=12.84;ReadPosRankSum=0.041;SOR=0.661", 
"AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=405;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;QD=33.41;SOR=0.858", 
"INFO", "AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=3.85;DB;DP=498;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=13.45;ReadPosRankSum=1.05;SOR=0.736", 
"AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.11;DB;DP=350;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=12.85;ReadPosRankSum=-4.640e-01;SOR=0.687", 
"INFO", "AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.635e+00;DB;DP=467;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.522;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=10.95;ReadPosRankSum=0.905;SOR=0.750", 
"AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-5.710e-01;DB;DP=478;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=31.82;ReadPosRankSum=-1.297e+00;SOR=0.369"
), VAR = c("BZ2257588", "0/1:186,205:391:99:0|1:11854457_G_A:5581,0,3667", 
"0/1:134,125:259:99:3353,0,3693", "1/1:0,400:403:99:13391,1205,0", 
"BZ2257689", "0/1:255,240:495:99:6688,0,6524", "0/1:188,160:348:99:4501,0,5131", 
"BZ2258942", "0/1:256,207:463:99:5099,0,7033", "1/1:1,477:478:99:15237,1392,0"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

As you can see, column names appear multiple times in the data frame. The first three columns have consistent names, but the fourth column's name is the patient ID, which I want to convert into a new column.

df2 <- structure(list(REF = c("T", "C", "T", "T", "C", "G", "T"), ALT = c("G", 
"G", "C", "G", "G", "A", "C"), INFO = c("AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=2.56;DB;DP=394;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=14.20;ReadPosRankSum=1.08;SOR=0.674", 
"AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=3.000e-03;DB;DP=263;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.451;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=12.84;ReadPosRankSum=0.041;SOR=0.661", 
"AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=405;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;QD=33.41;SOR=0.858", 
"AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=3.85;DB;DP=498;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=13.45;ReadPosRankSum=1.05;SOR=0.736", 
"AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.11;DB;DP=350;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=12.85;ReadPosRankSum=-4.640e-01;SOR=0.687", 
"AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.635e+00;DB;DP=467;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.522;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=10.95;ReadPosRankSum=0.905;SOR=0.750", 
"AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-5.710e-01;DB;DP=478;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;QD=31.82;ReadPosRankSum=-1.297e+00;SOR=0.369"
), VAR = c("0/1:186,205:391:99:0|1:11854457_G_A:5581,0,3667", 
"0/1:134,125:259:99:3353,0,3693", "1/1:0,400:403:99:13391,1205,0", 
"0/1:255,240:495:99:6688,0,6524", "0/1:188,160:348:99:4501,0,5131", 
"0/1:256,207:463:99:5099,0,7033", "1/1:1,477:478:99:15237,1392,0"
), ID = c("BZ2257588", "BZ2257588", "BZ2257588", "BZ2257689", 
"BZ2257689", "BZ2258942", "BZ2258942")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))


Copying the first code block didn't work for me until I wrapped quotes around 2257588  in "2257588" = c(...

What's the original source of this data? Are you reading from a file or website? I think a solution might be easier if you don't set the first row as column headers.

The row that is being used to populate the headers is actually data. You need to adjust the data-reading process so that row is in the data and then re-post your data.

Thank you very much for your question. My data comes from a file, and I can set header=F when reading it.

I apologize the first piece of code didn’t work. I will re-upload it.

First, import your data so that the first row is not headers:
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
write.csv(df, tmp, row.names = FALSE)

# If you already have your data as a CSV or similar, just add header = FALSE
# like this and ignore the above code (that's just for reproducibility)
df1 <- read.csv(tmp, header = FALSE)

Then, use tidyr::fill to copy down the IDs:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  # Add column names manually
  rename(
    REF = V1,
    ALT = V2,
    INFO = V3,
    VAR = V4
  ) %>%
  # Create a new column whhere IDs are kept as numbers and everything
  #   else is made into NA
  mutate(ID = as.numeric(VAR)) %>%
  # Fill in the NAs with the most recent ID value
  fill(ID) %>%
  # Remove rows that are actually headers
  filter(REF != "REF")



Well done. I came up with nearly the same solution but too slow :)
df <- df |> 
  mutate(ID = case_when(c3=="INFO" ~ c4, .default = NA)) |> 
  tidyr::fill(ID) |>
  filter(c1 != "REF")


Thank you very much for your help. In this case, due to the way the sample data was generated, all patient IDs are numbers. However, in the actual data, the IDs are a combination of letters and numbers, so as.numeric might not work. How should I adjust for this? Thank you.

@Pokemoon See gabagool's answer, it will be more robust to different ID formats.

Since df1 is already read into R, we can use it directly as shown below:
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID = cumsum(REF == 'REF')) %>%
  mutate(ID = VAR[1]) %>%
  filter(REF != 'REF')



Based on @Pokemoon comment, my solution might be more applicable
library(dplyr)
df <- df |> 
mutate(ID = case_when(V3=="INFO" ~ V4, .default = NA)) |> 
  tidyr::fill(ID) |>
  filter(V1 != "REF") |>
  rename(
    REF = V1,
    ALT = V2,
    INFO = V3,
    VAR = V4
  )

Credit to @Eonema: Edited to properly have default column names of V# and use rename.

Using base R to demonstrate another approach.
which + rep + diff:
i = which(df1$REF == "REF")
df1$ID = rep(df1$VAR[i], diff(c(i, nrow(df1) + 1)))
df1 = df1[-i, ]

where df1 is your data as given in question.
